# miranda with gtalk on custom domain

Tags: google-talk, miranda-im

In my new company we're using google hosted gmail and gtalk and we use our custom domain, so my email looks like `k102@mydomain.ru`.

I'd like to set up my MirandaIM to use gtalk, but can't understand how:
[image]
what domains should i enter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [google's docs](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=49157)

```
Username: Your Google Talk username (without any @ symbol or domain information)
Password: Your password
Login Server: mydomain.ru
Use SSL: Yes
Manually specify connection host: Yes
Host: talk.google.com
Port: 5223
Keep connection alive: Yes
```

should work

Comment: thanks! works now! i'll accept yours cause you was the first

Comment: Heh, by a millisecond maybe.  But also the most complete answer.

Answer (score 1):

These should be the other way around.

Use `mydomain.ru` in the Domain/Server field, and use `talk.google.com` in the Specify Connection Host field.

Answer (score 1):

Use "your domain" in Domain/Server option and in Mannually Specify connection host use "talk.google.com"

I hope it will work.